# Why is there a difference in crystal shapes of sodium chloride (NaCl) and potassium chloride (KCl)?

Tags: crystal-structure, salt

According to *[Sodium chloride](https://en.crystalls.info/Sodium_chloride)* and *[Potassium chloride](https://en.crystalls.info/Potassium_chloride)*:

Sodium chloride (NaCl) crystallizes, among various other shapes, into octahedron and tetragonal pyramid shapes which are absent in potassium chloride (KCl). I am a quite confused about this because both KCl and NaCl have a crystal structure. What is the explanation?

And what are some books where I can find the shapes that salt crystals form?

Comment: Crystal shapes are a complicated story.

Comment: There are some papers on that topic. The crystal habit/shape or in broader terms morphology depend a lot on concentration, temperature, impurities, etc. According to some papers that I found an octahedral shape can be achieved for KCl as well. So you might have to search for 'KCl octahedral morphology' and follow the cited papers. But it's a complicated story.

Comment: I feel the urge to reiterate once again that it is a really, _really_ complicated story. There is no simple rule.

Comment: Maybe you want to remove the last question as it is too broad.

Comment: Crystal habits from solutions containing additives differ because the interactions with these additives differ. Here is one example for sodium chloride: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.cgd.7b01170

Answer (score -1):

To compare between $\ce{KCl}$ and $\ce{NaCl}$ structure, you need to know what crystallographic planes are and their "distance between the atoms ratio".

$\ce{KCl}$ adopts a simple cubic system in which each atom lies at the corner of the cube.

[image]

The first set of planes ABFE, CDHG, ADHE, BCGF, ABCD, EFGH are alike. They are called (100) planes. Let the distance between the atoms be $\mathrm{d_1}$.

Parallel planes ADGF and ABGH are called (110) planes and are inclined at 45° to the cubic faces. Distance between atoms $\mathrm{d_2 = \frac{d_1}{\sqrt{2}}}$

Third set of planes like AFH are (111) planes. Distance $\mathrm{d_3 = \frac{d_1}{\sqrt{3}}}$.

Thus, for simple cubic system, $\mathrm{d_1 : d_2 : d_3 = 1 : \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} : \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}$.

This ratio is in agreement with practical values. However, this calculation doesn't answer if the $\ce{K}$ and $\ce{Cl}$ atoms are in alternative fashion. This can be answered when compared to $\ce{NaCl}$.

The values obtained for the planes of $\ce{NaCl}$ are almost similar to that of $\ce{KCl}$ except a weak reflection at the (111) planes at about 5°. This makes the ratio,  $\mathrm{d_1 : d_2 : d_3 = 1 : \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} : \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}}$ which agrees that $\ce{NaCl}$ adopts a face-centred cubic system.

[image]

This difference can be explained by the fact that the number of electrons (atomic number) determines the amount by which an atom scatters X-rays. Because the atomic number of potassium and chlorine are not that apart, $\ce{KCl}$ had adopted the simple cubic lattice but in case of $\ce{NaCl}$, difference between the atomic number between sodium and chlorine is more, hence they adopted the face-centred cubic lattice. But, we can say that **both $\ce{NaCl}$ and $\ce{KCl}$ have same structure but with different arrangement.**

Pictures taken from *Modern Physics* by Kiruthiga Sivaprasath, S. Chand Publishing, **2008**

Comment: I thought NaCl and KCl crystallized in the same spacegroup, with anions fcc and cations in "holes" with octahedral coordination. For KCl, your picture does not show a complete unit cell but just an eighth of it (KCl is not simple cubic).

Comment: At STP NaCl and KCl do crystallize in the same structure, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Rock_salt_crystal_structure . It is the CsCl structure that can be viewed as interpenetrating primitive lattices. I really don't understand what "both NaCl and KCl have same structure but with different arrangement" is trying to say.